# I want to run a command in the system shell then respond to the program i am running with the commands input prompt?

Tags: command-line, python-3.x

I am trying to

1. Send a command to the terminal
2. Respond to the program's input prompt in Python.

How can I do that? I know how to use subprocess.check_output to just get a return.

Comment: program < file doesnt work, it doesnt accept input that way, it prompts for password at the command line after u run the program in terminal

Comment: it is to pass the password to and encrypted dir, then append text to a file in the dir, then close the dir, re-encrypting it. to i have to pass the command "encfs ~/'encrypted-dir' ~/'open-dir' , then it will prompt for the password

Answer (score 0):

if you have your inputs in a file normally `<` symbol would do.

```
./executable < inputsfile
```

Comment: i need to pass a string, a password infact to the program i want my program to run in terminal

Comment: when i try ur way i get:   bash: some_string: No such file or directory (some_string is example password)

Comment: i tried saving it in a txt file, but no go, i would rather pass a string data anyway

Comment: i am not sure how the input handling in python works but in c if you are using `scanf` then `<` symbol do. so here i suppose your program is reading the input as a file, so try `./executable inputsfile` without `<`